# What is "it" indicating in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I once stole some apples at the market, but It was for my children starving, not for me.

What is "it" indicating in this sentence?
I think "it" indicates "I once stole some apples at the market".
But is it possible "it" can refer to a sentence this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible things that 'it' could refer to:

> I once stole some **apples** at the market, but It was for my children starving, not for me.

This seems reasonable at first glance, but since 'apples' is plural, it would say "but *they were* for", so we can rule this one out.

> I once stole some apples at the **market**, but It was for my children starving, not for me.

I only include this for completeness...I think it's safe to say that the entire market is not for her kids ;)

> **I once stole some apples at the market**, but It was for my children starving, not for me.

This, I believe, is what you are asking about. If 'it' can point to the entire phrase. Well, not quite, we need an actual noun for 'it' to refer to, but you're super close!

> I once **stole** some apples at the market, but It was for my children starving, not for me.

This is subtle, but points to the actual **act** of stealing being the 'it' in question. This is important because the what (apples) and where (market) are just details. The thing ('it') that was "for her children" was the stealing itself.

Comment: Your observation on my sentence was very interesting. :) And to add, is there a sentence in which **"it"** in the form of **"it was for..."** is referring back to the entire preceding sentence? If you make a one thing, it'd be very helpful to me.

Comment: Your own answer is close, but still not correct. *It* refers to **stole some apples at the market**. It's not *just* the stealing, it's the specific context. The apples and the markets aren't *only* details—they are *essential* to the referent of the pronoun. You could replace *it* with *that act*. What was the act? *Stealing some apples at the market.*